# How can i use PHP variable (fetch_array) on JS ? (json encode)

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to use code like this in script for my functions:

```
<script>
function selectCust(){
var data = <?php echo json_encode("$rs['name']"); ?>;
document.getElementById("txtfield").value = data;
}
</script>
```

I didn't work, i didn't want to use the hidden field. So, how will it work in simple way. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Drop those double quotes around PHP variable:

```
<script>
function selectCust(){
var data = <?php echo json_encode($rs['name']); ?>;
document.getElementById("txtfield").value = data;
}
</script>
```

Otherwise PHP will parse that string literally and you will just put "$rs['name']" string into your txtfield element.

Comment: Thanks, but it's won't work on onclick = selectCust(), if i use ordinary string it's show on textfield but it's wont work on rs['name'] any suggestion ?

Comment: do you need json_encode there? Check if $rs['name'] contains anything. Also you may try to `uft8_encode(json_encode($rs['name']))` if there are any "suspoicious" characters

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<script>
 function selectCust(){
       var data = "<?php echo json_encode($rs['name']); ?>";
       document.getElementById("txtfield").value = data;
 }
</script>
```